# running 'npm install' from shell also runs the 'prepublish' script

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

This is a SSCCE.
Given the following `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
      "prepublish": "echo \"pre-publish script called\""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.10.0"
  }
}
```

Running: `npm install` from the shell, results in the `prepublish` script also being executed:

```
$ npm install

> foo@1.0.0 prepublish /tmp/so
> echo "pre-publish script called"

pre-publish script called
npm WARN foo@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN foo@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN foo@1.0.0 No license field.
```

If the `prepublish` script gets renamed to e.g. `prepublis` it is no longer executed with `npm install`. Problem is, I need the `prepublish` script as I typically perform static type analysis and Mocha tests prior to publishing to npm.

Is this a bug or a feature and how do I get around it? There should be no need to run my Mocha tests when I simply wish to install the `package.json` dependencies.

My environment is:

```
$ npm --version && node --version
3.9.5
v6.2.2
```

Comment: this is NOT a bug.  see https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said it's not a bug (although everyone wants this functionality to be fixed), but there is a solution.  Check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/in-publish to help with this very situation.

### Solution summary

(from the in-publish package page)

```
 npm install --save in-publish
```

Then in package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "in-publish && thing-I-dont-want-on-dev-install || not-in-publish"
  }
```

You can also use `not-in-install` and `in-install` instead of `in-publish`

```
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "not-in-install && thing-I-dont-want-on-dev-install || in-install"
  }
```

Comment: Yeap that worked. However, I used `npm i --D in-publish` (I think in-publish should be a development time dependency only).

Answer (score 1):

**2023 UPDATE!**

The accepted answer here is great for 2016, but now there's a better solution which does not require installing a new package to work around npm... use the `prepublishOnly` script instead of `prepublish`.

This issue describes the problem, and proposes the `prepublishOnly` script, along with some other changes :
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10074

You can see if your version of NPM supports the prepublish script

```
npm -v
```

Navigate here :
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts?v=true
... and select the corresponding version of NPM to see whether it's supported.

`prePublish` is supported as of npm version 6.

Update your package.json :

```
"scripts": {
    "prepublishOnly": "whatever you previously had under publish"
}
```

Note that there is also a script called `prepare` which will run before install, so now you have more fine grained control over npm lifecycle scripts!